# Dodge Caravan 2007 Engine Whine

Tags: engine, noise

Smooth engine and transmission, one day suddenly started whining loudly after a brief stop.

Can feel the vibrations in the accelerator peddle. Whine dies down with high RPM (and above 60km/h), but returns as the RPMs come down again. Has random "spells" of these intense whine, but then the intensity of the whine tapers off after running it for awhile - but the "booming" whine is very audible as the car slows down or coasts at low speeds.

Read online that it could be the power steering reservoir, so I replaced that. Yet the whine persists.

I'm linking two videos that somewhat convey the whine. Hard to capture the whine as it's more "resonance" type of noise. Putting my ear everywhere and listening carefully, seems to be emitting from the center of the engine block itself and not the accessory belt or the alternator/pulleys.

What do you all reckon it could be?

Thanks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYzOFGpBbJ8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rx4nH7wGcLE

Comment: If you put the transmission in neutral and increase RPM does the whine increase? Or does it increase with speed independent of engine RPM?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It does sound like a power steering whine, as though it is low on fluid. If it isn't low on fluid, it could be the power steering pump. Not sure who told you to replace the reservoir, because unless it is leaking, there's nothing wrong with it. It is a static device, meaning it does nothing (no moving parts) except retain extra power steering fluid.

Comment: In Neutral, the noise is consistent to it being in Park or Drive - so no change. The noise increases with the RPM to a certain speed - like 40 kmph and then dies down or at least is subdued by the normal engine noise itself. As for the reservoir, doing a search for similar symptoms leads to several videos and forum discussions about steering reservoir screen being clogged and causing pump whine. So I thought I'd try that. The fluid is perfect level as I just changed everything. Thanks